# MySQL sum of two columns wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL query which contains a sum of two values from two different tables, comes out with a wrong result for some of the queries.

Table looking like this:

---

table 1

```
    ID  |  name  |  value         
    1   |  bla   |  88.666666     
    2   |  hi    |  90.555555      
    3   |  bye   |  80.444444
```

---

table 2

```
    ID  |  name  |  value         
    1   |  h     |  1.007275     
    2   |  na    |  22.005555      
    3   |  nh    |  23.007878
```

Then I want to add the values of bla and h together. I then do a simple query

```
SELECT a.`value`+b.`value` AS totalvalue from `table 1` a CROSS JOIN table 2 WHERE a.`ID` = 1 AND b.`ID` = 1
```

The result should be something like:

```
    89.673941
```

But it reality i get:

```
89.6739400000000000000000001
```

Both table types are TEXT, i have tried with DOUBLE but no difference. The tables constructed is just an small example, the tables i use is larger, and approx. 1 out of 3 results may be wrong as the example shows. I hope you can help.

Comment: Nothing is wrong - you're using floating point numbers.

Comment: Use `decimal` instead and look up the difference between fixed-point and floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with CAST as DECIMAL like

```
SELECT cast((a.`value`+b.`value`) AS decimal(10,6)) AS totalvalue
FROM `table 1` a
CROSS JOIN TABLE 2
WHERE a.`ID` = 1
  AND b.`ID` = 1
```

Comment: Worked beautifully . Thanks :)